# Can't pp (pretty print) in fxri? (ruby)

Tags: ruby

Here's a little copy/paste from fxri. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Ruby version is; *ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]* on 64 bit windows 7.

```
irb(main):334:0> pp "a"
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<FXIrb:0x6229524>
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/prettyprint.rb:146:in `text'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/prettyprint.rb:198:in `group'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/pp.rb:140:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:77:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/pp.rb:119:in `guard_inspect_key'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:77:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:60:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:59:in `each'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:59:in `pp'
from (irb):334
from :0

irb(main):335:0> a = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d"}
irb(main):336:0> a
=> {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d"}
irb(main):337:0> pp a
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<FXIrb:0x6229524>
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/prettyprint.rb:146:in `text'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/prettyprint.rb:198:in `group'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/pp.rb:140:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:77:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/pp.rb:119:in `guard_inspect_key'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:77:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:60:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:59:in `each'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:59:in `pp'
from (irb):337
from :0

irb(main):338:0> ary = Array.new(5) {|i| Array.new(5) {|j| i*j } }
=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]]
irb(main):339:0> pp ary
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<FXIrb:0x6229524>
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/prettyprint.rb:146:in `text'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/prettyprint.rb:198:in `group'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/pp.rb:140:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:77:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/pp.rb:119:in `guard_inspect_key'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:77:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:60:in `pp'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:59:in `each'
from ..../Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/PP.rb:59:in `pp'
from (irb):339
from :0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def <<(text)
  print text
end

irb(main):011:0> pp [1,2]
[1, 2]
=> nil
```

ruby 1.8.6 (2007-03-13 patchlevel 0) [i386-mswin32]

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Only downside is that I need to redo that each session (unless I learn how to hook it to loading of fxri), but that's no big deal. This seems to work in 1.8.7 also.

Comment: @pkauko: look into .irbrc

eg http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/05/30/irbrc-on-windows

Answer (score 6):

Try requiring explicitely pp

```
require "pp"
```

If this doesn't work, try to upgrade to ruby 1.8.7 or use another "pretty printer" such as [awesome print](http://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)

Comment: Had already tried that (forgot to mention) and upgrade didn't change anything (ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32] now).